# Consejo sobre guardar datos con los signals

Tags: python, django

Tengo dos modelos tarea y actividades, lo que estoy realizando es que cada vez que el usuario le de al proceso verdadero del modelo actividades, este se haga un conteo y se saque un porcentaje según la cantidad de actividades con el proceso en verdadero, lo que quiero hacer lo hace bien todo es según lo esperado, pero siento que mi solución no es la mas optima.

Este son mis modelos:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type_task = models.ForeignKey(TypeTask, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    state = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    porcentage = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task


class Activities(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    process = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Y este es mi signal:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Activities)
def calculate_porcentage(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.process:
        activities = Activities.objects.all().count()
        completed = instance.process

        porcentage = (completed * 100) // activities
        instance.task.porcentage = porcentage
        if porcentage == 100:
            instance.task.state = True
```

---

#### Actualización:

Aquí esta mi vista:

```
def task_update(request, slug):
    template_name = 'tasks/update_task.html'

    instancia = Task.objects.get(slug=slug)
    form = TaskForm(instance=instancia)
    formset = TaskFormSet(instance=instancia)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST, instance=instancia)
        formset = TaskFormSet(request.POST, instance=instancia)

        if form.is_valid():
            instancia = form.save(commit=False)

            instancia.save()

            if formset.is_valid():
                formset.instance = instancia
                activities = instancia.activities_set.count()
                completed = instancia.activities_set.filter(
                    process=True).count()
                total = (completed * 100) // activities
                if total == 100:
                    instancia.state = True
                    instancia.porcentage = total
                    Project.objects.update(status='approver')
                else:
                    instancia.state = False
                    Project.objects.update(status='process')
                formset.save()

                return redirect('tasks:task')

    return render(request, template_name, {
        'form': form,
        'formset': formset,
    })
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien el código de tu señal, pero creo que no tomaste en cuenta que **solo es "guardado" el porcentaje calculado de la ultima iteracion de bucle `for`**, ya que en cada iteracion estas asignando un valor al atributo `porcentage` de la instancia.

Comment: Ademas, dicha señal es del modelo `Activities`, es decir el parámetro posicional `instance` es una instancia de este, entonces... ¿de donde sacas el atributo `porcentage`? No se supone que deberías hacer esto a una instancia del modelo `Task`? (ya que dicho modelo tiene un campo llamado`porcentage` )  O es un atributo meramente "temporal"?... La verdad es que tu código no tiene sentido...

Comment: Tienes razon mi codigo no tenia nada de sentido el motivo por el que guarda era un codigo erroneo en la view, he modificado mi codigo y creo que esta vez tiene mucha mas logica que antes, y ahora si realizar el proceso que deseo con el signal, podrias verificar el codigo del signal.

Comment: Ahora analizando tu código, estas calculando mal el porcentaje, estas multiplicando `True` por `100`,  y ya que `True` es equivalente a `1` la operación que estas haciendo seria `1 x 100`, dando como resultado que el porcentaje calculado siempre sea `100` . No se si no te percataste, pero el valor del atributo `process` es boleano... y mas que nada no le encuentro sentido cuando declaras la variable `completed`, creo que te falto o te olvidaste de algo ahí...

Comment: no pude realizar la solucion por medio del signal, este se ejecuta varias veces por cada dato, asi que la solucion que deje fue que es mi view, donde obtengo todos los datos y despues los proceso.